# Interference between strokeopacity and fillopacity

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency

I have a few circles in a drawing, and want to highlight some of them.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (1,0);
\coordinate (A3) at (1,1);
\coordinate (B)  at (1,0);

\draw (A1) -- (A2);
\draw (A1) -- (A3);
\draw (B)  -- (A3);

\foreach \point in {A1,A2,A3,B} {
   \fill [black,draw=white](\point) circle (3pt);
}

\pgfsetstrokeopacity{.3}
\pgfsetfillopacity{.3}
\fill [red,draw,rounded corners,line width=9pt] (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3) -- cycle;
\pgfsetstrokeopacity{1}
\pgfsetfillopacity{1}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would like the whole area surrounding the A points to be of the same color,
but the strokeopaticy and the fillopacity interfere.

Is there some ay I can prevent this?

Note: in my actuall use scenario, there are too many coordinates for manual adjusting to be an option (otherwise I would just do with a fill with rounded corners, with points calculated manually).

Comment: To be honest, I don't really understand what you are trying to do. You are filling the area within the points A1..., right? So what do you mean by `the whole area surrounding` them? And why aren't you using `fill opacity=.3` or `opacity=.3` or whatever rather than the `\pgf...` settings? Why not just pass those in the options to `\fill`? Note that you are not *drawing* that path at all - only filling it. So `\pgfsetstrokeopacity` is not likely to do much.

Comment: Ooops, I copied the example from the wrong buffer. I have just edited the question to reflect my original situation (still, you did infer correcly in your answer!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not certain what you are trying to do but, right now, you are only filling the path - not drawing it. So the line width doesn't affect the visible output, for example.

I can't see any reason to resort to `\pgf...` here rather than using the TikZ options.

Here's one possibility:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (A2) at (1,0);
  \coordinate (A3) at (1,1);
  \coordinate (B)  at (1,0);
  \draw (A1) -- (A2);
  \draw (A1) -- (A3);
  \draw (B)  -- (A3);
  \foreach \point in {A1,A2,A3,B} {
    \fill [black,draw=white](\point) circle (3pt);
  }
  \filldraw [red, rounded corners, line width=9pt, opacity=.3] (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: transparent fill]

The reason for the darker parts is that TikZ fills *and* draws those, so the effective opacity there is doubled.

To avoid this, you can use a `transparency group`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (A2) at (1,0);
  \coordinate (A3) at (1,1);
  \coordinate (B)  at (1,0);
  \draw (A1) -- (A2);
  \draw (A1) -- (A3);
  \draw (B)  -- (A3);
  \foreach \point in {A1,A2,A3,B} {
    \fill [black,draw=white](\point) circle (3pt);
  }
  \begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=.3]
    \filldraw [red, rounded corners, line width=9pt] (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: transparency group]

Comment: Thank you! I did not know a) about the transparency options b) about transparency groups.